# Count flags for a variable (big) number of colums

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, sas

I have a table which looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyKt3.png

And I want a result like this:

```
Conditon    COL
ted1        4
ted2        1
ted3        2
```

I.e., the count of the number of '1' only in this case.

I want to know the total no. of 1's only (check the table), neglecting the 0's. It's like if the condition is true (1) then count +1.

Also consider: what if there are *many* columns? I want to avoid typing expressions for every single one, like in this case `ted1` to `ted80`.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? (Different products, with different versions of SQL.) And why the sas tag?

Comment: im working on sas as well as proc sql in SAS so i thought if some one could provide an answer in either would be great

Comment: "StackOverflow" Allows only 5 tags

Comment: This really is very basic SAS, you don't appear to have made any effort in attempting it first.  I suggest you look up `proc means`, have a go at getting the answer, then post a new question if you have any specific problems

Comment: Lalit was being sarcastic. We expect you to provide the actual RDBMS you are working with, not an arbitrary enumeration of popular systems. The solution depends on the RDBMS.

Comment: Why the insistence on SQL? Proc means will handle in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

Using `proc means` is the most efficient method:

```
proc means data=have noprint;
var ted:; *captures anything that starts with Ted;
output out=want sum =;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
sum(case when ted1=1 then 1 else 0 end) as ted1,
sum(case when ted2=1 then 1 else 0 end) as ted2,
sum(case when ted3=1 then 1 else 0 end) as ted3
from table
```

Comment: what if i have 10-20 variables i.e Ted1-Ted20

Comment: You may need to repeat that for all columns or Use PIVOT

Comment: repeating for all the columns is not an options because i could have as many as 80 columns for a table so

Comment: i tried macros combined with arrays to get the answer but not satisfied as its still not efficient.. remember im working on SAS and Procsql

Answer (score 0):

In **PostgreSQL** (tested with version **9.4**) you could unpivot with a `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` subquery. You'll need dynamic SQL.

This works for ***any* table with *any* number of columns matching *any* pattern** as long as selected columns are all **numeric** or all boolean. Only the value `1` (`true`) is counted.

Create this function *once*:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tagcount(_tbl regclass, col_pattern text)
  RETURNS TABLE (tag text, tag_ct bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT
     'SELECT l.tag, count(l.val::int = 1 OR NULL)
      FROM ' || _tbl || ', LATERAL (VALUES '
       || string_agg( format('(%1$L, %1$I)', attname), ', ')
       || ') l(tag, val)
      GROUP  BY 1
      ORDER  BY 1'
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
   AND    attname LIKE col_pattern
   AND    attnum > 0
   AND    NOT attisdropped
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tagcount('tbl', 'ted%');
```

Result:

```
tag  | tag_ct
-----+-------
ted1 | 4
ted2 | 1
ted3 | 2
```

The 1st argument is a valid table name, possibly schema-qualified. Defense against SQL-injection is built into the data type `regclass`.

The 2nd argument is a `LIKE` pattern for the column names. Hence the wildcard `%`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5367ee673bb69bcd683e9239b23b56d)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c3a82/1)</sub>

Related:

- [Select columns with particular column names in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800367/select-columns-with-particular-column-names-in-postgresql/15800497#15800497)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)