# Count the number of attributes that are NULL for a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, null, plpgsql

I want to add a new column to a table to record the number of attributes whose value are null for each tuple (row). How can I use SQL to get the number?

for example, if a tuple is like this:

```
Name | Age | Sex
-----+-----+-----
Blice| 100 | null
```

I want to update the tuple as this:

```
Name | Age | Sex | nNULL
-----+-----+-----+--------
Blice| 100 | null|  1
```

Also, because I'm writing a PL/pgSQL function and the table name is obtained from argument, I don't know the schema of a table beforehand. That means I need to update the table with the input table name. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible **without spelling out columns**. Unpivot columns to rows and count.

The aggregate function [`count(<expression>)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) only counts non-null values, while [`count(*)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) counts *all* rows. The shortest and fastest way to count NULL values for more than a few columns is `count(*) - count(col)` ...

Works for *any* table with *any* number of columns of `any` data types.

In Postgres 9.3+ with built-in [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) - count(v)
           FROM json_each_text(row_to_json(t)) x(k,v)) AS ct_nulls
FROM   tbl t;
```

What is `x(k,v)`?

`json_each_text()` returns a set of rows with two columns. Default column names are `key` and `value` as can be seen in the [manual where I linked](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). I provided table and column aliases so we don't have to rely on default names. The second column is named `v`.

Or, in any Postgres version since at least 8.3 with the additional module [**`hstore`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) installed, even shorter and a bit faster:

```
SELECT *,  (SELECT count(*) - count(v) FROM svals(hstore(t)) v) AS ct_nulls
FROM   tbl t;
```

This simpler version only returns a set of single values. I only provide a simple alias `v`, which is automatically taken to be table *and* column alias.

- [Best way to install hstore on multiple schemas in a Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146433/best-way-to-install-hstore-on-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgres-database/19146824#19146824)

Since the additional column is **functionally dependent** I would consider *not* to persist it in the table at all. Rather compute it on the fly like demonstrated above or create a tiny function with a [polymorphic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) input type for the purpose:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ct_nulls(_row anyelement)
  RETURNS int  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT (count(*) - count(v))::int FROM svals(hstore(_row)) v';
```

(`PARALLEL SAFE` only for Postgres 9.6 or later.)

Then:

```
SELECT *, f_ct_nulls(t) AS ct_nulls
FROM   tbl t;
```

You could wrap this into a `VIEW` ...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e8fd000340b7189d2561ffd2830bd1ea)* - demonstrating all
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/86a232/1)</sub>

This should also answer your second question:

> ... the table name is obtained from argument, I don't know the schema of a table beforehand. That means I need to update the table with the input table name.

Comment: by the way, can I ask what the x(k,v) is?

Comment: @KingstonChan: I added explanation for that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can express this as:

```
select t.*,
       ((name is null)::int +
        (age is null)::int +
        (sex is null)::int
       ) as numnulls
from table t;
```

In order to implement this on an unknown table, you will need to use dynamic SQL and obtaining a list of columns (say from `information_schema.columns)`).

Comment: We can make it work without dynamic SQL or visiting catalog tables in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a function to perform OP's requirement by using [Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31444686/3682599) with following table and data:

Table `det`:

```
CREATE TABLE det (
  name text,
  age integer,
  sex text
);
```

Data:

```
insert into det (name,age,sex) values
  ('Blice',100,NULL),
  ('Glizz',NULL,NULL),
  (NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Function:

```
create or replace function fn_alter_nulls(tbl text,new_col text)  returns void as 
$$
declare vals text;
begin
   -- dynamically getting list of columns *
select string_agg(format('(%s is null)::int',column_name),'+') into vals
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='public' and table_name=''||tbl||''  and table_catalog='yourDB_Name';
-- adds new column
execute format('alter table %s add column "%s" int',tbl,new_col);
--updates new column
execute format('update det set %s =(%s)',new_col,vals);
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

Function call:

```
select fn_alter_nulls('det','nnulls')
```

Comment: Nice automation. One flaw: user input should never be concatenated into dynamic SQL without escaping possible invalid syntax or SQL injection.  Likewise, all existing identifiers should be treated as user input.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks , Can you just elaborate it ?

Comment: That wouldn't fit into a comment. I added [another answer with the audited function.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31476672/939860)

Answer (score 1):

### Function to add column automatically

This is an audited version of what [@winged panther posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31449199/3682599), per request.

The function adds a column with given name to any *existing* table that the calling role has the necessary privileges for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_add_null_count(_tbl regclass, _newcol text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- add new col
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %I smallint', _tbl, _newcol);

   -- update new col with dynamic count of nulls
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT format('UPDATE %s SET %I = (', _tbl, _newcol)  -- regclass used as text
          || string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ' IS NULL)::int + (')
          || ' IS NULL)::int'
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
      WHERE  attnum > 0
      AND    NOT attisdropped
      AND    attrelid = _tbl  -- regclass used as OID
      AND    attname <> _newcol  -- no escaping here, it's the *text*!
      );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11fb0/1)

#### How to treat identifiers properly

- Sanitize identifiers with cast to `regclass`, `format()` with `%I` or `quote_ident()`.
  I am using all three techniques in the example, each happens to be the best choice where they are used. More here:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

I formatted the relevant code fragments in bold.

#### Other points

- I am basing my query on `pg_catalog.pg_attribute`, but that's a *optional* decision with pros and cons. Makes my query simpler and faster because I can use the OID of the table. Related:

  - [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
  - [Select columns with particular column names in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800367/select-columns-with-particular-column-names-in-postgresql/15800497#15800497)
- You have to **exclude the newly added column from the count**, or the count will be off by one.
- Using data type **`smallint`** for the count, since there cannot more than 1600 columns in a table.
- I don't use a variable but execute the result of the `SELECT` statement directly. Assignments are comparatively expensive in plpgsql. Not a big deal, though. Also a matter of taste and style.
- I make it a habbit to prepend parameters and variable with an underscore (`_tbl`) to rule out ambiguity between variables and column names.

Answer (score 0):

Since the null count is derived data and simple/cheap to determine at query time, why not create a view:

```
create view MyTableWithNullCount as
select
  *, 
  case when nullableColumn1 is null then 1 else 0 end +
  case when nullableColumn2 is null then 1 else 0 end +
  ...
  case when nullableColumnn is null then 1 else 0 end as nNull
from myTable
```

And just use the view instead.

This has the upside of not having to write triggers/code to maintain a physical null count column, which will be a bigger headache than this approach.